# Is the variant direct image mathematically significant?

Tags: reference-request, functions, notation, terminology

Preimages have the property that for an arbitrary function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and all $B \subseteq Y$ it holds that $$f^{-1}(B^c)=[f^{-1}(B)]^c.$$

However, the analogous statement for direct images is false. Thus, we have two definitions of direct image; the usual one, and a variant. $$f_*(A) = \{b \mid \exists a \in X : a \in A \,\wedge\, f(a)=b\}$$
$$f_\diamond(A) = \{b \mid \forall a \in X : a \in A \,\vee\, f(a) \neq b\}$$

Now I think (though I have not proved it) that, for all functions $f$, it holds that $f_* = f_\diamond$ iff $f$ is an <strike>injection</strike> bijection. Note also that, under these definitions, we have $$f_*(A^c) = [f_\diamond(A)]^c, \quad f_\diamond(A^c)=[f_*(A)]^c.$$

Here's another observation. If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, then we have that $f_*$ preserves openness iff $f_\diamond$ preserves closedness, and vice versa.

Okay, but does $f_\diamond$ have any *real* mathematical significance? Like, does it show up naturally in any interesting theorems etc.? If so, what's the standard terminology/notation, and where can I learn more?

---

**Addendum**. Two related maps are $f_\cap(A) := f_*(A) \cap f_\diamond(A)$ and $f_\cup(A) := f_*(A) \cup f_\diamond(A).$ If anyone knows where I can learn more, please leave a comment! Note that all four concepts coincide in the case of bijections.

Comment: Actually, the "variant" direct image is usually denoted by $f_*$, and its generalisation is studied in topos theory simply as the "direct image functor".

Comment: @ZhenLin, if the variant is usually denote $f_*$, what is the usual one denoted?

Comment: I've recently encountered these ideas in the book by MacLane and Moerdijk called *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic.* The two functors you describe are denoted $\exists_f$ and $\forall_f$ in the book and they are left and right adjoints of the inverse image functor. (The categories are the lattices of subsets.) I believe they give a beginning example of a geometric morphism, which appears to be quite important! I've just started this subject, so I'm afraid I'm not qualified to say much more about it, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variant direct image **is** universal quantification. So if you think universal quantification is significant...

To explain, let $X, Y$ be sets and let $f : X \times Y \to Y$ be the projection onto the second coordinate. If $\varphi(x, y)$ is any proposition involving variables $x \in X, y \in Y$, then it cuts out a subset of $X \times Y$ (namely the subset for which $\varphi(x, y)$ is true). The corresponding direct and variant direct image subsets in $Y$ are precisely the subsets of $Y$ cut out by the existentially and universally quantified statements $\exists x : \varphi(x, y)$ and $\forall x : \varphi(x, y)$ respectively.

---

Much more generally, let $F : C \to C'$ be a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) between two [categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) and let $D$ be another category. Then $F$ induces a functor $D^{C'} \to D^C$ between [functor categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category). A left [adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) to this functor, if it exists, is called **[left Kan extension](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension)** along $F$, and a right adjoint is called **right Kan extension**.

Now let $C, C'$ be sets regarded as discrete categories (categories with only identity morphisms), and let $D = \{ 0 \to 1 \}$ be the category with two objects $0, 1$ and a single non-identity morphism $0 \to 1$. $D$ is a poset, and so are the functor categories $D^C, D^{C'}$, which are naturally identified with the poset of subsets of $C, C'$ under inclusion. If $F : C \to C'$ is a functor (so just a map of sets), the induced functor $D^{C'} \to D^C$ is the usual preimage functor, the usual direct image is the left Kan extension along $F$, and the variant direct image functor is the right Kan extension along $F$.

Left and right Kan extension are ubiquitous in mathematics; Mac Lane famously said that they subsume all the other fundamental concepts in category theory. So it is a little hard to give examples because there are so many. This example is the simplest example I know.