# Why are complete lattice homomorphisms defined that way?

Tags: functions, order-theory, lattice-orders

Given a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and a set $A \subseteq X$, there's at least two possible ways of interpreting the direct image $f(A),$ as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405446/is-the-variant-direct-image-mathematically-significant). In the notation of that question, write $f_*(A)$ for the usual direct image, and $f_\diamond(A)$ for the variant. The definitions are as follows.

$$f_*(A) = \{b \in Y \mid \exists a \in X : a \in A \,\wedge\, f(a)=b\}$$
$$f_\diamond(A) = \{b \in Y \mid \forall a \in X : a \in A \,\vee\, f(a) \neq b\}$$

Note that in the case of <strike>injections</strike> bijections, we have $f_* = f_\diamond$. Observe also that these definitions are dual, in the sense that $[f_\diamond(A^c)]^c =  f_*(A)$ and $[f_*(A^c)]^c =  f_\diamond(A).$

Now in lattice theory, we have the following definition: given complete lattices $L$ and $M$ and a function $f : L \rightarrow M$, we say that $f$ is a *complete lattice homomorphism* iff $$f\left(\bigwedge A\right) = \bigwedge f_*(A), \quad f\left(\bigvee A\right) = \bigvee f_*(A)$$

Why is it defined this way? What would happen if we instead required:

$$f\left(\bigwedge A\right) = \bigwedge f_\diamond(A), \quad f\left(\bigvee A\right) = \bigvee f_\diamond(A)$$

??? Note that, whenever $f$ is <strike>injective</strike> bijective, these two definitions coincide.

Comment: The standard definition is what you would get if you regard the theory of complete lattices as a variety of infinitary algebras. Is that not a good enough reason?

Comment: @ZhenLin, perhaps. How does one define the homomorphisms in a variety of infinitary algebras?

Comment: The same way as in varieties of finitary algebras: they preserve the various operations of the algebra. (The operations of a complete lattice are, of course, all the $\kappa$-ary joins and meets, as $\kappa$ varies over all cardinals.)

Comment: @ZhenLin, righto well let me chew on that for a bit.

Comment: @ZhenLin, so basically we have a cardinal-indexed sequence of meets for $L$, denote them $\bigwedge_\kappa^L$ and another such sequence $\bigwedge_\kappa^M$ for $M$, and we require that for all cardinals $\kappa$ and all functions $A : \kappa \rightarrow L$ it holds that $f\left(\bigwedge_\kappa^L A\right)=\bigwedge_\kappa^M f \circ A$. And similarly for joins.

Comment: @ZhenLin, sorry I hope I'm not badgering you; but if you don't mind me asking, is the above definition correct?

Comment: Yes. But I'm sure you could have worked that out on your own.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I did work it out on my own. But I just wanted confirmation. The associated [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_%28universal_algebra%29) is strangely silent on the definition of what the morphisms are between elements of a variety.